Can't suppress warning from transformers/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py
My implementation for the AutoModel AutoTokenizer classes are fairly simple:
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
from rank_bm25 import BM25Okapi
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

class EmbeddingModels:

    def bert(self, model_name, text):
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
        inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, padding=True)
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).detach().numpy()
        return embeddings
    
    def create_chunks(self, text, chunk_size):
        return [text[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(text), chunk_size)]

But I can't get this warning to go away:
A parameter name that contains 'beta' will be renamed internally to 'bias'. 
Please use a different name to suppress this warning.
A parameter name that contains 'gamma' will be renamed internally to 'weight'. 
Please use a different name to suppress this warning.

There is no reference to the word beta or gamma anywhere in my repo.
Updating the package, suppressing the warnings with import warnings

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Before loading from pretrained model set transformers logger level to error as shown below. It sure is really frustrating not being able to leverage the warnings library filter
    loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
    for logger in loggers:
        if "transformers" in logger.name.lower():
            logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    # now you can load state dict from pretrained
    model = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained(
        "bert-base-uncased",
        use_safetensors=True,
        return_dict=False,
        attn_implementation="sdpa",
    )


This worked! Thank you so much, I can't tell you the amount of times I banged my head on a my desk trying to get this to go away!
